# Run cordova phonegap through a specific ide

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, aptana, aptana3

I would really like if someone of your very well-known community could help me.

Here is what I try to do. I try to run apache cordova through aptana using `Ripple` and `Android Emulator`

I am using aptana studio 3 for web development IDE and I try to configure it in order to develop phonegap apps. I have OS Windows 8.1 64

I have `Java sdk`
I installed `Android sdk`
I have `Node JS`
I have the cordova phonegap using `npm install -g cordova` in the C

I have installed Ripple emulator as plugin in Chrome. In order to run it through aptana I go to the run arrow and I select Run Configurations and making a new configuration using in 
Browser Executable: the path for chrome.exe
Arguments: --enable-extensions --allow-file-access-from-files

And run it.

Also I go to Help --> Install New Software in order to take the android developer tools. I click in the right up corner the button Add and I give the name ADT and location https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Everything work. I tried to insert an existing phonegap project and run it but I have a problem to show the android emulator. Any help how can I do it?

Also any help how I will run a new phonegap example in order to make my own app and test it with Ripple and Android Emulator? Also can I install plugins like `org.apache.cordova.splashscreen`

Comment: Here a video for ADT which helped to see in eclipse what link to set but in 6:48 I can see file --> new --> android project even if I run it on eclipse or aptana https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVjCMXQGS_w

Comment: Here is another video which helped me with Ripple emulator around 3:01 it shows how to configure it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B13BU4gcn-g

Comment: If anyone could help me to make some step forward it will be amazing! thank you!